# Непоследовательное выполнение команд в java, android.

Tags: android, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в android. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на клик по кнопке ставлю вызов диалога выбора файла. Этот метод определяет путь до файла. Затем этот путь просто вывожу на TextView. Все в логике просто. Да вот он сначала(!) выводит пустой путь на TextView, и только затем открывает диалог. Т.е как будто пропускает вызов диалога, делает остальные действия, и только потом вызывает диалог. Почему так и как с этим бороться? Заранее огромное спасибо.`private String Temp;
        public void dialog(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FileDialog.class);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.START_PATH, "/sdcard");`

```
            intent.putExtra(FileDialog.CAN_SELECT_DIR, true);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SAVE);
}

public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        int resultCode, final Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Temp = data.getStringExtra(FileDialog.RESULT_PATH);

        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txtInfo.setText("NOO");
        }
public void test(View v)
{ 
    dialog(v);
    TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtInfo.setText(Temp);

}
```

test = onClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String Temp;
        public void dialog(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FileDialog.class);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.START_PATH, "/sdcard");

            intent.putExtra(FileDialog.CAN_SELECT_DIR, true);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SAVE);
}

public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Temp = data.getStringExtra(FileDialog.RESULT_PATH);
                txtInfo.setText(Temp);

        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            txtInfo.setText("NOO");
        }
public void test(View v)
{ 
    dialog(v);
}
```

если что не понятно, спрашивай :)

2 совета

> test = onClick.

что бы это не объяснять и самому не путаться, называй методы сразу правильно, например `testOnClick(View v)`

старайся вызывать метод findViewById как можно реже, у тебя его достаточно было вызвать 1 раз в onCreate(View v), а не каждый раз в onActivityResult

Comment: Спасибо большое конечно =) Но для одного случая, да, у меня удавалось сделать. Проблема в том, что мне, вообще, необходимо реализовать по клику на кнопку алгоритм, при котором получается путь до файла, посредством dialog(), затем этот путь записывается глобальную переменную. Это надо сделать для 6 различных кнопок и, соответственно, 6 разных переменных. Но вот беда, он сначала записывает в переменную пустое значение (или, если смотреть на вопрос, то в txtInfo.setText(Temp)), а только потом вызывает dialog(). Почему так непоследовательно? ;)

Comment: если смотреть в вопрос, то сначала вызывается диалог, а потом записывается значение (метод test())

Comment: Да, так и должно быть) по-логике все должно идеально работать. вот в этом то собственно и вопросик) почему сначала значение передается, а потом только dialog() вызывается ? =)

Comment: мой вариант пробовал?

Comment: это для одной переменной работает. а, например, чтобы в другую переменную путь положить? подобно этому:
public void testOnClick(View v)
{ 
dialog(v);
TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Temp2 = txtInfo.getText().toString(); 
}
public void test2OnClick(View v)
{
dialog(v);
TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Temp3 = txtInfo.getText().toString();
}
если запустить так, то при выполнении первой командой вызывается не dialog(),а Temp2 = ... Вот и вопрос: почему первым вызывается не dialog(). Хоть и в коде его вызов идет первым)Может с потоками как то?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String Temp;
        public void dialog(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FileDialog.class);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.START_PATH, "/sdcard");

            intent.putExtra(FileDialog.CAN_SELECT_DIR, true);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SAVE);
}

public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Temp = data.getStringExtra(FileDialog.RESULT_PATH);
                txtInfo.setText(Temp);

        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            txtInfo.setText("NOO");
        }
public void test(View v)
{ 
    dialog(v);
}
```

если что не понятно, спрашивай :)